# How do I print “What happened on the 4th of June 1989?” in BrainFuck?

Tags: brainfuck

I need to learn how to display this text in BrainFuck among other programming languages, BrainFuck included.

Comment: I don't really get why you included a rant against the CCCP, but SO is partially blocked in China thanks to scripts from Google, among other things. There's also [no restrictions on criticism of the CCCP here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/), but it's considered noise in questions and answers. Feel free to use your profile (and/or username) for it, though. Was something blocked when you tried posting the question? Mentions of Tiananmen square aren't usually blocked, but I can help you edit whatever you initially had planned in if you still can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the following code in Brainfuck to generate that.

```
+[--->++<]>+.+++[->++++<]>.-------.--[--->+<]>-.[---->+<]>+++.-[--->++<]>--.-------.-[++>-----<]>..-----------.+++++++++.---------.-.-[--->+<]>-.+++++[->+++<]>.-.-[->+++++<]>-.---[->++++<]>.------------.---.--[--->+<]>-.++[-->+++<]>+.++++++[->++<]>.------------.--[--->+<]>--.+++++[->+++<]>.---------.[--->+<]>--.+++++[->++<]>.-[----->+<]>.-------.---------.--[--->+<]>-.[-->+++<]>+.++++++++.-.+.++++++.
```

This is a code generated from [Brainfuck text generator](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/text.html)

Truly brain fucked. (upvoted btw)